# Rewrite Batch command as Powershell for Jenkins build step

Tags: powershell, batch-file, jenkins, windows-installer

I need to change this batch command to powershell:

```
WfWI.exe x.msi /c /o xy/x.msi /l xy/wfwi.log /s
```

I need to implement this command in jenkins powershell build step.

Comment: have you tried running it in a PoSh shell? have you tried adding that line to a powershell script & testing it? what did not work?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I tried it didn't show any error. .log file and output file not generated.

Comment: @NagaJyothiP - kool! now ... please put that info and any other info you have on what does and does not work in the original post so others can see it without needing to read thru the comments. [*grin*] you also probably should mention what the EXE file is and what the options are - or post a link to that information.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you use one of theses ?

```
cmd.exe /c "WfWI.exe x.msi /c /o xy/x.msi /l xy/wfwi.log /s"

& "WfWI.exe x.msi /c /o xy/x.msi /l xy/wfwi.log /s"

WfWI.exe x.msi /c /o xy/x.msi /l xy/wfwi.log /s | cmd
```

Comment: I have tried .. but xy/x.msi and xy/wfwi.log are not generated.

Comment: Are they generated when using cmd.exe directly ?
Because that's odd, they shouln't. Maybe the issue come from your command itself.